# Mondogb $sum not working with SchemaTypes.Double

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i'm fairly new to MongoDB and Mongoose and i'm working on a bug here. Apparently `$sum` is not working with a field whose type is `SchemaTypes.Double`. This double type is available thanks to a package called `mongoose-double`.

I don't know if MongoDB doesn't support Double so that's why we have this package, or is this because of MongoDB Version (it's on 3.6 AFAIK). But anyways, here's the code:

```
Schedule.aggregate([{
    $match: findTerm
  },
  {
    $facet: {
      totalizer: [{
        $group: {
          _id: '$store',
          totalServices: {
            $sum: 1
          },
          totalValue: {
            $sum: '$value'
          },
          totalComission: {
            $sum: '$comissionValue'
          }
        }
      }
      ],
      data: [{
        $project: {
          'employee.name': 1,
          'customer.name': 1,
          'service.name': 1,
          'info.channel': 1,
          value: 1,
          scheduleDate: 1,
          scheduleStart: 1,
          scheduleEnd: 1,
          comissionValue: 1,
          status: 1,
          paymentMethod: 1
        }
      },
      {
        $sort: sort
      },
      {
        $skip: req.body.limit * req.body.page
      },
      {
        $limit: req.body.limit
      }
      ]
    }
  }
  ]).exec((e, response) => {
    if (e) {
      // handle error
    }
    res.status(200).send(response[0]);
  });
```

This `findTerm` is sent by the frontend app and has this format:

```
{ store: '5b16cceb56a44e2f6cd0324b',
  status: { '$in': [ 0, 1, 2, 3 ] },
  paymentMethod: { '$in': [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ] },
  'info.channel': { '$in': [ 'app', 'admin' ] },
  scheduleStart: { '$gte': '2019-11-01 00:00' },
  scheduleEnd: { '$lte': '2020-03-31 23:59' }
}
```

My `comissionValue` field is in the root of my Schedule Schema:

```
comissionValue: {
  type: SchemaTypes.Double,
  default: 0
},
```

But my result is the following, as shown in my console.log in the frontend
[image: Results]

As you can see my `totalComission` inside my `totalizer` is `null`, but my first object inside `data` has a `comissionValue` of `0.6`.
How can i kno what's wrong here? I've tried different combinations of `$facet`, filtering only Schedules that has a `comissionValue` not equal 0 and null, but i only got a result of 0 for `totalComission`.

### EDIT

Here's some sample data:

A Schedule object:

```
customer: {
  id: "5e41a7ba11340930742aa689",
  name: "renan  lima",
  phone: "+5511999999999",
  email: "sampleemail@gmail.com",
  doc: "00000000000",
  avatar: null
},
employee: {
  id: "5b16cebd29bcf613f02b6fb4",
  name: "Anderson Zanardi",
  avatar: "anderson.jpg"
},
service: {
  noValue: false,
  filters: [],
  id: "5b637acd634e14086c9a3aea",
  name: "Barba Masculina"
},
info: {
  channel: "app",
  id: "5e41a7ba11340930742aa689",
  name: "renan  lima"
},
comissionType: null,
comissionValue: 0,
paymentMethod: 0,
_id: "5e41a7c011340930742aa68a",
store: "5b16cceb56a44e2f6cd0324b",
scheduleDate: "2020-03-16T15:00:00.000Z",
scheduleStart: "2020-03-16 09:00",
scheduleEnd: "2020-03-16 09:30",
status: 2,
value: 30,
color: "blue",
logStatus: [],
__v: 0,
created: "2020-02-10T18:58:08.845Z",
updated: "2020-02-10T18:58:08.845Z"
```

My response received for the `Schedule.aggregate`:

```
{
  "totalizer": [{
    "_id": null,
    "storesCount": [{
      "store": "5b16cceb56a44e2f6cd0324b",
      "count": 12
    }],
    "totalValue": 410.5,
    "totalServices": 12,
    "totalComission": 75
  }],
  "data": [{
    "_id": "5e5d04dcb4a2f42204598ebf",
    "service": {
      "name": "Outros"
    },
    "info": {
      "channel": "admin"
    },
    "comissionValue": 0,
    "paymentMethod": 0,
    "customer": {
      "name": "teste"
    },
    "employee": {
      "name": "Gabriel Barreto"
    },
    "scheduleDate": "2020-03-02T13:06:00.000Z",
    "scheduleStart": "2020-03-02 10:06",
    "scheduleEnd": "2020-03-02 10:36",
    "status": 0,
    "value": null
  }]
}
```

Here the comission is 75, i don't know if it's because of the `scheduleStart` and `scheduleDate` in the `findTerm` on my `$match` that this time is starting at 2020-03-01 and ends at 2020-03-31 and in that range there's 3 schedules with 25 of comission.
Maybe my pagination is making it return null? Since i need it to sum all my comission for a given start/end range, even if in a certain page it doesn't have a comission.

### EDIT 2

I added a sample data in Mongo Playground, the schedule array in the configuration column matchs the query used in the $match property on the query column.
Here's the link: https://mongoplayground.net/p/nmyAsY4g7LS

Comment: Can you post please your sample data as text? So we can help you find the solution

Comment: @Valijon hi, sorry, totally forgot to add some data. I edited my question, does it help or do you need more data?

Comment: Can you please share "25" schedule documents to reproduce your issue [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xz_DJ1Cb6_s). Click Share and post the link in your question

Comment: @Valijon didn't know about Mongo Playground, nice tool. I added the schedules to correspond the $match on the query.

Comment: In the mongo playground it worked as expected, i'll now see if there's someting wrong in my requisition's body